# Django пишет непонятную ошибку

Tags: django

```
def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        recipient = 'tesmidev@gmail.com'
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            try:
                send_mail(name, phone, 'onskrer@gmail.com', recipient)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('chp/thanks.html')
    else:
        #Заполняем форму
        form = ContactForm()
    #Отправляем форму на страницу
    return render(request, 'chp/thanks.html', {'form': form})
```

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect('chp/thanks.html')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

в чем заключается ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: Нет блока `except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас еще проблема с отступами. Попробуйте удалить отступы перед

```
send_mail(name, phone, 'onskrer@gmail.com', recipient)
```

и

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('chp/thanks.html')
```

А затем заново поставить, но только либо таб либо пробелы. Так как проблема в этом и была

Comment: Если б были смешаны табы с пробелами, то ошибка была бы другая: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`.

Comment: да, оно и было. случайно включил в vs code опцию insert spaces

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте блок `except`.

***Пример:***

```py
try:
    send_mail(name, phone, 'onskrer@gmail.com', recipient)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: пробовал уже, unindent does not match any outer indentation level